# custom function to select and click a random element in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm new to e2e testing (and JS). I use Nightwatch framework.

I'm trying to create a function that selects a random element from a list of elements with the same selector, and clicks on it.

This is what I tried:

```
  pickOne(selector, target) {
    this.api.elements(selector, target, function(res) {
       optionsLength = Math.floor((Math.random() * res.value.length) + 1);
    });
    this.api.waitForElementVisible(`${target}:nth-child(${optionsLength})`);
    this.api.click(`${target}:nth-child(${optionsLength}) .action-button`);
  }
```

But in this case, `optionsLength is not defined`.

`Math.floor((Math.random() * res.value.length) + 1)` returns a number. I want to use this number outside of the function.

I've tried to store the full function in a variable, as in:

```
const optionsLength = this.api.elements(selector, element, function(res) {
       Math.floor((Math.random() * res.value.length) + 1);
    });
```

But that way `optionsLength` logs `[object Object]` instead a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define 2nd and 3rd functions in callback is not good, it would lead to callback hell.

You should use `.perform()` api instead , it will chain your functions :

```
pickOne(selector, target) {    
            this.api.elements(selector, target, function(res) {
               optionsLength = Math.floor((Math.random() * res.value.length) + 1);
            })
             .perform(function (client, done) {
                 console.log(optionsLength) ;// ***you can access optionsLength in above function***

                 done();
            })
```

This is docs from nightwatch [Perform](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#perform)

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the function with arrow syntax and wrapping everything into the callback has solved the (scope) issue.

Arrow syntax allows to keep calling `this.api.x` in the callback.

```
  pickOne(selector, target) {
     this.api.elements(selector, target, res => {
        optionsLength = Math.floor((Math.random() * res.value.length) + 1);
        this.api.waitForElementVisible(`${target}:nth-child(${optionsLength})`);
        this.api.click(`${target}:nth-child(${optionsLength}) .action-button`);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Once you have the element index `optionsLength`, you can also directly click it with `this.api.elementIdClick(res.value[optionsLength].ELEMENT);`

Answer (score -1):

```
function postimgname() {
var date = new Date();
var str =$scope.data_user.user_id + "" +date.getFullYear() + "" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "" + date.getDate() + "" +  date.getHours() + "" + date.getMinutes() + "" + date.getSeconds() 
+ "" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 ;
return str;
```

}